# Pylint tests directory with src layout raises import-error

Tags: python, pylint, tox, pyproject.toml

I'm using the following src layout:

```
src
├── packagename
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── subpackage
│       └── __init__.py
│       └── somemodule.py
├── .pylintrc 
│   ...
tests
├── subpackage
│   └── __init__.py 
│   └── test_somemodule.py
├── __init__.py
├── .pylintrc
│   ...
pyproject.toml
```

We perform linting of tests directory, with some relaxed rules defined at `tests/.pylintrc`. We had no problem with this when using a non-src layout.
`pytest` is working properly thanks to the following directive at `pyproject.toml`, albeit might had also been solved by installing the package with tox:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "src"
]
```

When running lint as:

```
pylint --rcfile src/packagename/.pylintrc -j 0 src
pylint --rcfile tests/.pylintrc j 0 tests
```

we are getting errors such as `E0401: Unable to import 'packagename.subpackage' (import-error)`.

How could this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to modify the Python path in an init-hook in your `.pylintrc`, e.g.

```
[MASTER]
init-hook=
    import sys
    sys.path.append("./src")
```